# PostgreSQL:How to insert values in an array into a table

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

for example,

<kbd>myelems</kbd> is my table

```
create table myelems (id int,element text)
```

and if I have an *array*

```
ARRAY['A','B','C']
```

then how to insert the *values* in the above *array* into my table *myelems*?

i.e,

```
 id|element 
---+-------
 1 |A
 2 |B
 3 |C
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
insert into myelems select row_number() OVER () AS rn,* from 
(select unnest(Array['A','B','C'])) as t
```

Comment: what if `insert into myelems select row_number() OVER () AS rn,* from 
(select unnest(Array['X','Y','Z'])) as t` , yes the `id` will repeat in the next insert and so on

Comment: `should not` auto-increment: why? What prevents you from using a very standard behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that ID by default is generated from a sequence, you can use:

```
INSERT INTO myelms(myelms) 
SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['A','B','C'])
```

However if you don't have a sequence and need to specify an id, you can use two unnest to insert your data.

```
INSERT INTO myelms(id,myelms)
SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1,2,3]),UNNEST(ARRAY['A','B','C'])
```

using the second option requires you to have the same number of elements in both unnest or else you will get the Cartesian product of both which will result in data that you do not want. And of course you need to make sure the ID is not in there already.

IDs should generally be generated from sequence since having to create your own ID can cause problems and duplicates. Since there are no other columns beside elements, I will assume that ID is your primary key, and all keys need to be unique.